# HTML/CSS custom button in "Our team" section

Tags: html, css, button

I want to recreate this kind of "His work" button but I don't know where to start. Can someone give me some directions ? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if its possible to recreate this 4 squares icon with the css, but for me the most simple way to do this is to insert an image inside.
Please check this link : https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/four-squares to see if you can use it

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I've think about this solution also but I'm not sure if I can make an image button on hover ?

Comment: I tryed with a svg bootstrap icon, i just put my <SVG> inside my button and add my content btn inside a <p> with "d-inline" class its work fine. Not sure if this will answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

```css
 button{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width:40%;
      padding: 10px;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      background: #fff
  
    }

    div{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;

    }
```

```html
   



       <button>
        <div>
          <img src="your icon"></>
          <P> HIS WORK </P>
        </div>

        <div>
          <img src="icon"></>
          <img src="icon"></>
        </div>
        </button>
```

Comment: thanks, your snippet code helps a lot